# Virtual destructor for CustomVertex in DIRECTX9

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-9, vertex-buffer

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so forgive me if my question is dumb.
I am trying to simply render a triangle in DirectX9 in Visual Studio 2012 following this: www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-4.

When I create a CUSTOMVERTEX class with a non-virtual destructor it renders the triangle without any problem. Whereas if I make the destructor virtual the triangle is not rendered.

Here is the code with the virtual destructor:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

// global declarations
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the vertex buffer

// function prototypes
void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void render_frame(void);    // renders a single frame
void cleanD3D(void);    // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void init_graphics(void);    // 3D declarations
// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);



//************CUSTOMVERTEX CLASS**********/
class CUSTOMVERTEX {
public:
    CUSTOMVERTEX( float _X, float _Y, float _Z, float _RHW, DWORD _COLOR )
        : X(_X), Y(_Y), Z(_Z), RHW(_RHW), COLOR(_COLOR)
    {}

    virtual ~CUSTOMVERTEX(){
        OutputDebugString("Destructed!!!\n");
    }
    float X, Y, Z, RHW;
    DWORD COLOR;
};

// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          0, 0,
                          SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    initD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        render_frame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    cleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp struct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    init_graphics();    // call the function to initialize the triangle
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

        // select which vertex format we are using
        d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

        // select the vertex buffer to display
        d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

        // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
        d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);

    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void cleanD3D(void)
{
    v_buffer->Release();    // close and release the vertex buffer
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
}


// this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
void init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX class
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        CUSTOMVERTEX(400.0f, 62.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255)),
        CUSTOMVERTEX(650.0f, 500.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0)),
        CUSTOMVERTEX(150.0f, 500.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0)),
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(3*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &v_buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Rendered triangle:[Rendered Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pDLU.png)

The code without virtual destructor:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

// global declarations
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the vertex buffer

// function prototypes
void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void render_frame(void);    // renders a single frame
void cleanD3D(void);    // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void init_graphics(void);    // 3D declarations
// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);



//************CUSTOMVERTEX CLASS**********/
class CUSTOMVERTEX {
public:
    CUSTOMVERTEX( float _X, float _Y, float _Z, float _RHW, DWORD _COLOR )
        : X(_X), Y(_Y), Z(_Z), RHW(_RHW), COLOR(_COLOR)
    {}

    ~CUSTOMVERTEX(){
        OutputDebugString("Destructed!!!\n");
    }
    float X, Y, Z, RHW;
    DWORD COLOR;
};

// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          0, 0,
                          SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    initD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        render_frame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    cleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp struct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    init_graphics();    // call the function to initialize the triangle
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

        // select which vertex format we are using
        d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

        // select the vertex buffer to display
        d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

        // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
        d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);

    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void cleanD3D(void)
{
    v_buffer->Release();    // close and release the vertex buffer
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
}


// this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
void init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX class
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        CUSTOMVERTEX(400.0f, 62.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255)),
        CUSTOMVERTEX(650.0f, 500.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0)),
        CUSTOMVERTEX(150.0f, 500.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0)),
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(3*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &v_buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Rendered without any triangle: [without any triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZORm.png)

Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: You hand the object over to a C-API-Function? Than it has to be a POD. Making the destructor virtual makes the object non-POD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Adding the `virtual` changes the memory layout of the structure, meaning your data is no longer in the correct place for the Vertex Declaration you provided:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX {
    CUSTOMVERTEX( float _X, float _Y, float _Z, float _RHW, DWORD _COLOR )
        : X(_X), Y(_Y), Z(_Z), RHW(_RHW), COLOR(_COLOR)
    {}

    float X, Y, Z, RHW;
    DWORD COLOR;
};
```

The size of this structure is 20 bytes.

```
class CUSTOMVERTEX {
public:
    CUSTOMVERTEX( float _X, float _Y, float _Z, float _RHW, DWORD _COLOR )
        : X(_X), Y(_Y), Z(_Z), RHW(_RHW), COLOR(_COLOR)
    {}

    virtual ~CUSTOMVERTEX(){
        OutputDebugString("Destructed!!!\n");
    }
    float X, Y, Z, RHW;
    DWORD COLOR;
};
```

The size of this structure is 24 bytes for x86 (Win32) and 32 bytes for x64 native. This is because there's a pointer to the vtable added at the start of the structure (and on x64 the additional padding pushes it out a little more than 8 bytes).

Furthermore, since you are using the type through a Direct3D Vertex Buffer, it's never going to have it's constructor or destructor executed. It's just allocated from the heap as a "plain old data type". The only time constructors or destructors are invoked for heap-allocated memory is via `new`, `new []`, `delete`, and/or `delete []`. Internally Direct3D Vertex Buffer is doing something more akin to `malloc`.

Your constructor is being invoked by the C++ compiler when you create the initialized array `vertices`, and the destructor is invoked when `vertices` goes out of scope.

In other words: This doesn't do what you think it does. Don't use `virtual` in your vertex data structures.

> Note that you should consider making using of a smart pointer like `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` for managing the lifetime of your Direct3D COM objects. This takes advantage of the C++ scoping rules for ctors/destructors to properly call `Release` automatically. Of course, you should also not be spending a lot of time learning legacy Direc3D 9 either.